# Dispatch refresh - how to automate

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

Any thoughts on how to automate the dispatch refresh command? It appears you can only dispatch refresh from the CLI.

I would go down one of these routes:

- Executing a .exe from Azure function on a e.g. weekly basis
- Set up dispatch refresh cmd in release management in Azure DevOps (should be possible)

What do you think, is there another way I haven't thought of yet?

EDIT: my dispatch model contains QnA KBs, which will be updated from time to time. Doing dispatch refresh only when we deploy would not be enough to keep the dispatch model up to date. That is why I am looking at timed jobs. Could this be achieved using CI/CD in Azure DevOps (whilst not deploying every week)?

Comment: This might be a bit opinion-oriented, but it sounds like you're on the right track (functions app that runs an .exe would be my personal preference). One other option is a [powershell runbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-runbook-types#powershell-runbooks)

Comment: I would do it in your Azure DevOps CI/CD flow, instead of running an Azure Function on a weekly basis. Make it part of your test and deploy strategy.